# В модальном окне fancybox не открываются ссылки

Tags: fancybox, javascript

Приветствую!

Столкнулся с проблемой использования плагина фенсибокс и никак не могу решить ее. Относительно недавно установил этот плагин модальных окон к себе на сайт для отображения картинок. Установил, все работает. Теперь решил выводить аналогичным образом в модальные окна ссылки на гугл-карты, то бишь чтоб карта открывалась не в новом окне, а в модальном.

Но... Проблема... Внешние ссылки вообще отказываются открываться в модальном окне, в нем отображается только белый экран. Как ни гуглил, ни крутил кодом и ссылками - внешние ссылки не открываются. В то же время страницы моего же сайта там открываются без проблем.

Что еще заметил - в примере урока по фенсибоксу на руселлере такая же проблема - белый экран вместо страницы. А вот на страницах офсайта фенсибокс в примерах все работает... WTF? В смысле, кто шарит - помогите, пожалуйста, советом или наводкой на причину проблемы.

Comment: @YuraSG, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

так? по клику на ссылку открытие карты

http://szsi.com.ua/page/link-open-map/

Comment: да, именно

Comment: только это яндекс,который реализуется через джаву. Мне же нужно чтоб работали ссылки без всяких джав, т.к. эти ссылки будут видоизменяться в зависимости от внесенного контента (адрес - координаты на карте)

Comment: а причем здесь yandex map к ссылке?

Comment: http://szsi.com.ua/page/link-open/ - вот без карты